# Should a gitignore template be selected based on the repo's main language?

Tags: git, github

I've never created a repository until now and in the process within Github, it asks for a gitignore template to select. I can't find any documentation on what it should be selected on - is it the repo's main language? Or another factor that goes into it?

Comment: The `.gitignore` is a file that specifies what files are not committed (ignored) and pushed to GitHub. Languages used in your project are a good start as you don't want language specific build files in your GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would make sense.

Keep in mind that that is only the first version of `.gitignore` and that you can change it later according to your needs.

For an example, if you decide to create a new app in your repository which is written in another language, you can find a `.gitignore` template for that language and just append it to your existing `.gitignore`.